# Docker error: Cannot create container for service web: invalid mode

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm having three errors when i run docker:

> ERROR: for learningphp7_web_1  Cannot create container for service web: invalid mode: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/virtualhosts.conf
>
> ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: invalid mode: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/virtualhosts.conf
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

How can i solve these issues and finally start using docker?

My `virtualhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory /var/www/html/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
    Options FollowSymLinks
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          Options -MultiViews
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 34):

Check your docker-compose.yml file. I recently had the same error, due to an extra space in the volume config:

```
  volumes:
  - ./www:/home/distressedpro/public_html
   - ./conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Note the extra space on the last line, that was causing the error. Correcting it to:

```
  volumes:
  - ./www:/home/distressedpro/public_html
  - ./conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

fixed it

Comment: Merci, 
yml invalid well established

Comment: In my case it was because I ended a quote but have not started it in a volume (*cough* Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V *cough*), but your answer helped.

Comment: in my case it was  this :                                                                                                                    volumes:                                                                                                                               - './magento:/var/www/html:delegated ' changed to                                                     - './magento:/var/www/html:delegated'    ==> remove space end of delegated because this was causing the erreur of creating container , i wanna share this to give more information about this issus for the beginner like me

Comment: My issue was that I had a colon in my filename. I was using a windows path for my volume. So it was like `/c:/Users/...`. Removing the colon fixed my issue. So it became `/c/Users/...`.